# Mouseover effects with anchors and corresponding divs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").mouseover(function(){
var currentId = $(this).attr('id')+"S";
$(".stay:visible").hide("explode",[],200);
$("#" + currentId).show("bounce");
});
});

.stay { 
display:none;
      }
<body>
<div id="parent">
  <a id="aaa"></a>
  <a id="bbb"></a>
  <a id="ccc"></a>
  <div id="holder">
     <div class="stay" style="display:inline"></div><!--Starting Div, leaving on first mouseover-->
     <div class="stay" id="aaaS"></div>
     <div class="stay" id="bbbS"></div>
     <div class="stay" id="cccS"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have my anchors and a corresponding div for each and a shared class="stay". The divs start out hidden, and on mouseover of the corresponding anchor I would like them to display in a holder div.  The divs contain an image, and when i had it all individually scripted quick mousing would result in all the divs stacked down the page.  Tried .stop() and .clearqueue() to no avail, so I wanted to try one catch all process.  The issue is it doesn't recognize the anchor as being the element I am asking for the ID of.  I'm really knew to this so any help is appreciated. 
Edit - I have the divs being selected now, but they are still stacking down the page if i mouse over the anchors too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)  super happy with the results.